# Why is my stack trace not showing any app code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When running a rake task `bundle exec rake db:setup` I get an error because I can't connect to the DB. However the stack trace never show where in my app or the rails rake task code this is originating from. Here is the stack trace that is spit out.

What is causing this stack trace?

**update**

I know that the cause of the problem is not being able to access the database. My question: why can't I see in the stacktrace which code is attempting to access the database?

```
The driver encountered an unknown error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:23:in `initialize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:68:in `initialize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/adapter.rb:1275:in `initialize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12:in `jdbc_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/connection_methods.rb:45:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `checkout'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in `create'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:87:in `create_current'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/tasks/databases4.rake:12:in `each_current_configuration'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/tasks/databases4.rake:11:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `create_current'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `run'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1099:in `load'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/bin/rake:23:in `(root)'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"app_snapshot", "pool"=>500, "username"=>"john", "password"=>nil}
The driver encountered an unknown error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:23:in `initialize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:68:in `initialize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/adapter.rb:1275:in `initialize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12:in `jdbc_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/connection_methods.rb:45:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `checkout'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in `create'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:87:in `create_current'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/tasks/databases4.rake:12:in `each_current_configuration'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/tasks/databases4.rake:11:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `create_current'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `run'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1099:in `load'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/bin/rake:23:in `(root)'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"app_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"john", "password"=>nil}
```

Comment: ... If you can't connect to the server you'll never get past Rails' config during setup.

Comment: yep i know :) see my clarified question above.

Comment: What makes you think the stacktrace doesn't show what's trying to access the DB? Are you concerned because most of that code is dynamic?

Comment: for some reason it didn't register that database_tasks contained the rake task i was invoking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the code that is calling it.

`bundle exec rake db:setup` isn't something you created, and therefore wouldn't be likely to reference your code.

The code is being run by `/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:23:in`initialize'` which is being run by the line below, etc.

I think these lines are as close as you're going to get to being interesting and relevant:

`/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in 'connection'`

`/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in 'create'`

`/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in 'create'`

`/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:87:in 'create_current'`

Comment: oh! right there under my nose. I was disregarding it while scanning over it. I even did text search for "rake" and "rails" to find task code, but didn't search for "task"... doh.